# command wrapped in os.system is ignored

Tags: python, macos, merge, limits, os.system

(on  os x 10.10.1)I am trying to use a paired-end merger (Casper) within a python script. i'm using os.system (don't want to use subprocess or pexpect modules). In my script here is the line that doesn't work:

```
os.system("casper %s %s -o %s"%(filein[0],filein[1],fileout))
#filein[0]: input file 1
#filein[1]: input file 2
#fileout: output prefix (default==casper)
```

Once my script is launched only the 2 first string parameters of this command are interpreted but not the third one, causing an output file with the default prefix name. Since my function is iterating through a lot of fastq files, they are all merged in a single "casper.fastq" file.
I tried to mess up with the part of the command that doesn't work (right after -o), putting meaningless string and still it is executed with no error and the default output, here is the "messed up line":

```
os.system("casper %s %s -ldkfnlqdskgfno %s"%(filein[0],filein[1],fileout))
```

Could anybody help in understanding what the heck is going on?

Comment: I also tried to check the os.sytem return value and it was 0 so it should be ok, but still this output problem is occurring

Comment: Shot in the dark - are there spaces in your file names? If so, `'casper "%s" "%s" -o "%s"` might work. Does `subprocess.call(['casper', filein[0], filein[1], '-o', fileout])` work?

Comment: Have you tried using print instead of os.system? just to check that the string is being constructed correctly

Comment: I'M BAFFLED! i tried to print the command, and the string has nothing wrong.

Comment: Moreover i have already tried a "subprocess.call" on my command but it returns an error i don't get: "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "stage_ruffus.py", line 329, in <module>
pipeline_run(multiprocess=4)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ruffus/task.py", line 3767, in pipeline_run
raise job_errors
ruffus.ruffus_exceptions.RethrownJobError:
Original exceptions:
Exception #
'exceptions.OSError([Errno 2] No such file or directory)' raised in ...
Task = def merge_read(...):
       Job  = [[393W_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq, 393W_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq] -> 393W_S1_L001_MERGED_READS_001.fastq]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Print the command before execute it to check if your command wrapped correctly(like file name need to be quoted)
2. Execute your assumed output command directly to see if it is misinterpreted.

Comment: i have already checked the command, by printing it and it seems ok. I'm not sure about the meaning of execute "directly"? if you mean "execute the printed command outside the script, in a terminal: i did and there's something weird happening: it's still gives me the default output.

Comment: Your idea was great, executing the printed command in the terminal indicates that there's a problem with the command itself: either i have output options issues or the filenames in the string should be quoted. i'm going to figure this out, but THX HUAZHIHAO, i should have thought about that!  if you have more clues, do not hesitate to share them

Comment: Done! it is really weird, in the Casper tool helper, it is written: "***Usage   : CASPER forward.fastq reverse.fastq [OPTIONS]***". Therefore my command is : "***casper file1 file2 -o output_prefix***" but it doesn't work. reformulating the command, starting with option instead of file input "***casper -o output_prefix file1 file2***"  WORKS

Comment: Sorry that I have no idea about casper and its parameter list. I just express my usual experiences about how to deal with bash execution. I must confess it doesn't cover each and every case. Sometimes, you also need to deal with environment - I mean user,path,acl, etc. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Haha, it really happens to OSX sometimes. Some command executed perfectly well under debian, but for OSX, it needs to be better formatted/restrained.